# yiic: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection

Tags: php, yii, console, yiic

My DB connection works perfectly in web application. But when I try the same settings in console application it fails (I wrote connection settings in console.php file).

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'host' (using password: YES)
```

I can't solve problem for 4 hours. What might be wrong?

Comment: if show showed us what both your `main.php` and `console.php` look like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to connect to the same DB which you connect to in your web application then copy your `'db' => array(...)` in config/main.php to config/console.php

Answer (score 0):

In console.php change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`